# Want to display duplicate values in cascading input controls

Tags: jasperserver

I work for a pharmacy. One way of classifying drugs is an identifier called GPI. The digits in the GPI have meaning, and a parent-child relationship.

[image]

In my database, I have a table of groups, a table of classes (includes groups), and a table of subclasses (includes groups and classes). The number values for classes are repeated over the groups. For example, group 01 might have class 01, 02, 03, and 04. Group 02 might also have 01, 02, 03, and 04. The classes are different in each group, they use have the same identifier.

In JasperReports Server 4.7 I have a multi-select query input control that displays the GPI groups. I also have a multi-select query cascading input control that takes the gpi_group value to display a list of classes. Here's the query that populates the cascading input control:

```
 SELECT DRUG_GROUP, DRUG_CLASS, CLASS_NAME
 FROM Schema.DRUG_CLASSES
 WHERE $X{IN, DRUG_GROUP, gpi_group}
 ORDER BY DRUG_GROUP, DRUG_CLASS
```

Visible columns: DRUG_GROUP, DRUG_CLASS, CLASS_NAME

Value column: DRUG_CLASS

And it works great when I select one drug group. Here's group 01:

[image]

And here's group 02:

[image]

But when I select them together:

[image]

The input control doesn't seem to like the duplicate values of the GPI Class that occur when multiple GPI Groups are selected. If I change the value column to GPI Class Name (where there are no duplicates) the display is as desired:

[image]

However, I don't want my value column to be the GPI Class Name, I want it to be the GPI Class. I'd like to constrain my GPI Subclass input control on the values that come from the GPI Group and GPI Class input controls, and I'd like to feed GPI Group, GPI Class, and GPI Subclass into my query.

Any thoughts on how I can get that cascading input control to display the 'duplicate' GPI Class values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I've decided to do --

The input controls want a unique value in the value column. I don't think there's any way around this so I'm just going to roll with it. I'll handle the concatenated strings in my query.

Query for GPI Class cascading input control:

```
 SELECT 
   DRUG_GROUP, 
   DRUG_CLASS, 
   CLASS_NAME, 
   DRUG_GROUP||DRUG_CLASS AS GROUP_CLASS
 FROM Schema.DRUG_CLASSES
 WHERE $X{IN, DRUG_GROUP, gpi_group}
```

Value column: GROUP_CLASS (a concatentation of GPI Group and GPI Class)

Query for GPI Subclass cascading input control:

```
 SELECT 
   DRUG_GROUP, 
   DRUG_CLASS, 
   GROUP_CLASS, 
   DRUG_SUBCLASS, 
   GROUP_CLASS_SUBCLASS,      
   DRUG_SUBCLASSNAME 
 FROM (
     SELECT 
       DRUG_GROUP, 
       DRUG_CLASS, 
       DRUG_GROUP||DRUG_CLASS AS GROUP_CLASS, 
       DRUG_SUBCLASS, 
       DRUG_GROUP||DRUG_CLASS||DRUG_SUBCLASS AS GROUP_CLASS_SUBCLASS, 
       DRUG_SUBCLASSNAME
     FROM Schema.DRUG_SUBCLASSES
 )
 WHERE $X{IN, GROUP_CLASS, gpi_class_cas}
```

Value column: GROUP_CLASS_SUBCLASS (a concatenation of GPI Group, GPI Class, and GPI Subclass)